# extract the selected value from a dropdown list with Thymeleaf and Spring boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My problem is that I can't get the value selected by the dropdown list,the error is:

**Field error in object 'agence' on field 'admin': rejected value [1]; codes [typeMismatch.agence.admin,typeMismatch.admin,typeMismatch.com.example.demo.entities.Adminstrateur,typeMismatch]; ; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.demo.entities.Adminstrateur' for property 'admin'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.demo.entities.Adminstrateur' for property 'admin':**

addagence.html:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/addAgence}" th:object="${agence}" method="post">

                        <div class="row">
                             <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                <label for="adresse" class="col-form-label">Adresse</label> <input type="text"  class="form-control"  name="adresse"> 
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                <label for="ville" class="col-form-label">Ville</label> <input type="text"  class="form-control"  name="ville"> 
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                <label for="admin" class="col-form-label">Administrateur</label>      

                                <select 
                                  class="form-control" th:field="*{admin}">
                                <option value="">Select Admin</option>
                                <option th:each="a: ${admins}"
                                  th:value="${a.codeUtilisateur}"
                                  th:text="${a.nom}"></option>
                                   </select>            
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Agence" >
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-8"></div>

                        </div>
                    </form>

A
```

dminController.java:

```
@GetMapping("signupAgence")
    public String showSignUpForm(Agence agence,Model model) {
        List<Utilisateur> admins=adminServices.getAdmins();
        model.addAttribute("admins", admins);
        return "addagence";
    }
@RequestMapping(value = "/addAgence")
    public String addAgence(Model model, Agence ag) {
        Agence agence = adminServices.addAgence(ag);
        model.addAttribute("agence", agence);
        return "redirect:/agence";
    }
```

Comment: I really need your help , it's urgent

Answer (score 0):

Here `th:field="*{admin}"` you are binding the selected option's value (which is a String since the value of a select option is NOT an object), to an Admin object. This is wrong and it's the cause of your error.

You have to change your command object so it can recieve the admin ***ID*** on it. Later you can search for the full admin object in your backend, or alternatively you can add all admin information on hidden inputs and recover them in the controller on form submission (this still won't save you from having to bind your select to a String field in your command object).

Comment: Sorry,but I didn't got you.Could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

If your admin object has an "id" property(and it should) you change:

```
th:value="${a.codeUtilisateur}"
```

To this:

```
th:value="${a.id}"
```